# Dell PowerEdge R310 and T310 not allowing 6x 4GB RDIMM configuration

Tags: dell, memory, dell-poweredge

I have 6 identical Kingston KTD-PE313E/4G modules and trying to install to Dell PE R310 and T310 servers but with no luck.

4x DIMMs works but not 6x DIMMs. None of the modules are faulty. (I have already tried to replace them)

Any ideas?

**Solved:**
Turns out the Kingston KTD-PE313E/4G is unbuffered DIMM and according to the manual, R310 and T310 only support 4x U-DIMM or 6x R-DIMM.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Please post your answer in the Answer box below, and then accept it, so that others know the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the Kingston KTD-PE313E/4G is unbuffered DIMM and according to the manual, R310 and T310 only support 4x U-DIMM or 6x R-DIMM.